# How is content type inheritance set?

Tags: content-type, wcm

I am building a WCM site. I have a custom Content Type for my pages, set at the Site Collection level. When I create a sub site, however, that content type is not present in the Document Library Settings.

When I go to edit the default page for the site, the new, custom Content Type is not available.

How can I change this behavior. I would not want to have to manually add the Content Type each time I create a site.

Answer (score 1):

If created at the site collection root, the content type will be available to all subsites.  If you create a document library template from a library with those content types enabled, you can provision new libraries in subsites with those set already.

Comment: I did create the Content Type (and associated site columns) at the Site Collection root, yet there is no inheritance to sub sites. Maybe a setting somewhere that I missed?

Comment: Did you check the subsite content type gallery? The content type should appear ther eif it was created at the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom Content Type for pages, then you should also create custom Page Layouts which are associated with the Content Type. As changing Page layout is going to change the content type of the page to the content type associated with the Page Layout.

If you to that, then the mere act of selecting the "right" Page Layout will add the corresponding content type to the Pages Library and change the page to use it.